Intuition question about length contraction
I'm self studying special relativity, and have started length contraction. I'm reading a problem that is (I'm paraphrasing):
A hovercar 10 meters long is flying towards a hole 8 meters long. The hole sucks in cars that are smaller than 8 meters long. How fast can the car go before it is sucked in.
My work:
we need to contract the body from $10$ down to $8$ meters. So, we have $$\frac{L}{L'}=\frac{10}{8} = \frac{5}{4}=\gamma$$
$$\implies \frac{5}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\implies \frac{4}{5}=\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{16}{25}=1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\implies \frac{v^2}{c^2}=\frac{9}{25}$$
$$\implies v = \frac{3}{5}c$$
So, we only have to be going at $\frac{3}{5}c$ or above in order to fall in.
My question is on what happens from the perspective of the hovercar (or person driving it). Shouldn't they see the hole contract? And even if the hole doesn't contract, how could they fall into the hole, given that they are 10 meters long and the hole is 8 meters long? What happens from the driver's perspective?

Be careful with simultaneity! This is the barn pole paradox.

Does this answer your question? Pole in the Barn Paradox

Think separately about what happens to the front of the car and what happens to the back of the car, in both frames.
